# Galaxy S not working with Home Cinema set

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s

I'm trying to connect my galaxy s (froyo, i9000) with usb to a Samsung Blu-ray Home Cinema system. Though, for some reason, the home cinema set won't recognise my phone.

I tried the samsung kies setting, the storage setting, and media player setting, but it just won't recognise it.

With someone else's blackberry it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that this would be somewhat of a "driver" issue. It seems that your Home Cinema system does not know what your device is and it cannot connect to it.

I would try seeing if there is a firmware update for the system (if it supports firmware updates).

It recognizes the blackberry because they have been around for so long, and they probably use the same driver to communicate with just about any blackberry.